# QSqlTableModel submitall but database is not updated

Tags: sqlite, qt-creator

I have a QTableView and a QSqlTableModel. When I update cells in the QTableView, I'm calling the "submitall" function to update the database.

"Submitall" is activated but there is no changes in the database and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
connect(ui->tableView->model(), SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)), this, SLOT(slot_commitChanges()));

QSqlTableModel *biensEssentielsModele = new QSqlTableModel();
biensEssentielsModele->setTable("biensEssentiels");
biensEssentielsModele->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
biensEssentielsModele->select();
biensEssentielsModele->removeColumn(0);
```

The slot_commitChanges() function :

```
if(biensEssentielsModele->submitAll())
    qDebug() << "OK"; // This is the input I get
else
    qDebug() << "NOK";
```

I also tried to use transactions, but the results are the same.
The database is SQLITE.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks :).

**EDIT : I forgot to mention that my database is a sqlite file.**

**UPDATE : I've just realized that when I add a row (with a button which call a slot "slot_addBiensEssentiels"), changed made in 1 cell is updated in the database. When it's done, other cells are not changed**

Here is my piece of code of the slot "slot_addBiensEssentiels" :

```
biensEssentielsModele->insertRow(biensEssentielsModele->rowCount());
```

Comment: How do you verify that the database is not updated?

Comment: The QTableView is refreshing with the same value. Moreover, I'm checking my sql file with a sqlite client.

Comment: Do not open the sqlite client when you run your application, probably blocking or overwriting the database.

Comment: This is what I thought, but the behavior is the same even if the sqlite client is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what was the problem.
I had to change :

```
biensEssentielsModele->removeColumn(0);
```

to :

```
ui->tableView->hideColumn(0);
```

The "removeColumn()" caused some issues when trying to update the database because of the missing column and reference.